# how to make a shape of an arc in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, I don't know much about making shapes. I want to make this screen, I know that I would need to use stacks, but occasionally I don't have the slightest idea of doing what I'm marking in red.

[image]

how can I do it?

Comment: You can use `CustomClipper` for that..

Comment: Hope [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter-aa197bda94bf) would be helpful..